# Mvc validation regular expression only numbers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I tried the following code for digits-only validation for a contact number validation in Mvc web app.

```
[RegularExpression(@"/(^\(\d{10})?)$/", ErrorMessage = "Please enter proper contact details.")]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Contact No")]
public string ContactNo { get; set; }
```

But the validation expression is not working.

For the contact number I want to only accept digits. It can be either a 10 digit mobile number or a land-line number.

Comment: What format should the contact number be? Can it contain spaces or dashes?

Comment: define "properly", what's improper about it?

Comment: it might be anything like can have 10 digit mobile number or handline to so thats why I jy=ust need to take an digits as an input

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/ /` is javascript way to build a regular expression literal object. In .NET you should not use it.

Try the following:

```
@"^\((\d{10}?)\)$"
```

or if you want exactly 10 digits:

```
@"^(\d{10})$"
```

Answer (score 16):

If don't have any restrictions other than numbers only, this should fit:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter proper contact details.")]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Contact No")]
public string ContactNo { get; set; }
```

Comment: so basically you use a regex to determine if the string is all digits.

Comment: Thanks sir, your answer actualy help to me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{10}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter proper contact details.")]
```