# how to put a regex valid range check on textboxvalue in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and I have this regex validation check in my model:

```
[RegularExpression(@"/^[1-7]$/", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid day number")]
public string DayNr {get;set;}
```

the validation check does not work however:( what is incorrect in the above code?

Answer (score 2):

it should be something

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[1-7]$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid day number")]
public string DayNr {get;set;}
```

for number validation go over this link.
[Mvc validation regular expression only numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839827/mvc-validation-regular-expression-only-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Do this - much simpler, more readable, easier to maintain:

```
[Display(Name="Day Number")]
[Range(1, 7, ErrorMessage = "{0} value must be between {1} and {2}")]
public string DayNr { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps